# go to the next step if {{!EXTRACT}} is true

Tags: regex, macros, eval, imacros

i'm new here and newbie in `imacros` and `javascript`
I have made a script that will extract a random word from a page with a regex syntax.

The script is working fine, is going to page.. is search for the word and if is there will extract the word.

But i need that the script is to refresh the page until the word is found and after that to run the second imacro script

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
SET !TIMEOUT 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=url
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"raspuns":\[\"(.[^"]*)" EXTRACT=$1
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
```

and if the word is found run the second script (if not refesh)

```
    TAB T=2
URL GOTO=url
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=AUTOCOMPLETE:off CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLICK:sendMessage()&&CLASS:go&&TXT:
```

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: In order to solve this issue you should master [the JavaScript Scripting Interface for Firefox](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface).

Answer (score 0):

Not super sure if I know exactly what you want and as it is imacros there are some weird workarounds but this might help you

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
SET !TIMEOUT 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=url
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"raspuns":\[\"(.[^"]*)" EXTRACT=$1
SET !VAR0 raspuns
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET !VAR2 EVAL("('{{!VAR0}}' == '{{!VAR1}}') ? 1 : 0;")  
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=url
TAG POS={{!VAR2}} TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=AUTOCOMPLETE:off CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
TAG POS={{!VAR2}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLICK:sendMessage()&&CLASS:go&&TXT:
```

As you didnt give a url its very hard for me to test, but point is, if if takes the word youre looking for, raspun, it will set the TAG position to 1, therefore tagging what you need, but if it doesnt, it will set the TAG pos = 0, therefore just passing through the code, hope that helps